# Concatenate and minify AMD modules without r.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

I have a project which is using a lot of AMD modules. How do I approach combining and minifying those modules without using the r.js optimizer? If all of my AMD modules are named, can I just safely concatenate and minify them?

Comment: Is there any reason for not using r.js?

Comment: @kryger yes - our project is in PHP and I'd rather prefer not to force node.js stack on developers, even if just for building.

Comment: @Amy I'd rather avoid node.js stack, as then we'd only eb using it for this amd optimization.

Answer (score 1):

> If all of my AMD modules are named, can I just safely concatenate and minify them?

It depends. For simple enough setups, the answer is "yes". For instance, if you have module `A` defined as `define('A', ['B'], function (B) { return ... });` and `B` as `define('B', function () { return ... })` and the config you pass to `require.config` is such that requesting the modules can be requested as `A` and `B`, then you could merely concatenate them and minify them with whatever tool you want. You could skip using `r.js`.

For more complex setups, concatenating and minifying without using `r.js` is asking for trouble. `shim` configurations, for instance, require special handling. The order in which shimmed modules are put in an optimized bundle matters and `r.js` creates `define` stubs for them so that any dependencies they need are loaded first and anything defined in a shim's `exports` option is actual exported.

Comment: when I concat and minify dependencies and use almond -> do I still have to define requirejs.config paths?